# Another expected class name before '{' token c++ inheritance issue

Tags: c++, class, oop, templates, inheritance

Can't seem to find where the error is. I do not think there is a circular implementation issue. I am pretty sure all of the .h files are included where they need to be. Array is inheriting from BaseArray:

The error:

```
In file included from driver.cpp:6:0:
Array.h:10:1: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
 {
```

BaseArray.h:

```
#ifndef _BASEARRAY_H_
#define _BASEARRAY_H_

#include <cstring>

template <typename T>
class BaseArray
{
    public...
}
#include "BaseArray.inl"
#include "BaseArray.cpp"

#endif   // !defined _BASEARRAY_H_
```

BaseArray.cpp:

```
#include "BaseArray.h"
#include <stdexcept> 
#include <iostream>

//..Constructors, Destructors, Functions...
```

Array.h:

```
#ifndef _ARRAY_H_
#define _ARRAY_H_

#include "BaseArray.h"
#include <cstring>


template <typename T>
class Array: public BaseArray
{
public:
    ......
};
#include "Array.inl"
#include "Array.cpp"

#endif   // !defined _ARRAY_H_
```

Array.cpp

```
#include "Array.h"
#include "BaseArray.h"
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
//
// Array
//


template <typename T>
Array <T>::Array (void): BaseArray<T>()

//...more and more code
```

Comment: `BaseArray` is a template, so it needs a type, probably `class Array: public BaseArray<T>`.

Comment: Awesome! That worked. I'm really new to Inheritance and Templates so a lot of this is over my head.

Comment: BaseArray.h includes BaseArray.cpp, and BaseArray.cpp includes BaseArray.h. There is the same problem with Array.cpp.  Suggest using different extension for a file that is included rather than forming its own translation unit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
class Array: public BaseArray
```

to this:

```
class Array: public BaseArray<T>
```

since `BaseArray` is a template class.

Moreover, in your header file you don't put a semicolon at the end of your class.